# When would you use a write-only file?

Tags: security, permissions, file-permissions

Read-only files may be useful for configuration settings that are unlikely to change, but what about write-only? As the system can still execute binary write-only files, can someone give an example as to where this would be a good thing to do, security- and programming-wise?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. 3 obvious scenarios are data diodes, printers and logs.

Comment: I meant this question from a programming point of view, and I've clarified that. I would disagree on logs, why would you want them to be unreadable in case of an error?

Comment: Too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: And what if there too many possible answers? The best ones will receive high reputation, so one can easily read the best ones. It is better to have too many answers than nothing.